# Using @UniqueElements annotation for a List of Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to add a check for a List of Students `List<Student>` based on their `phone_number`.

```
Student : {
  id, name, rollNo, phone_number
};
```

I have a Class and in the class all students must have a unique phone number.

```
Class : {
  classId, name, 
  //Here I want to add @UniqueElements by Hibernate over the field of `phone_number` of `Student`.
  //@UniqueElements 
  List<Student>
}
```

I tried to find some help in such complex DS but only found examples for Basic DS like `List<Integer>`.

Can someone help me to find how can I accomplish this task?

---

**Note** : Like is there some option for eg: `@UniqueElements(validateBy="phone_number")` through which I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need override `hashCode` and `equals` in class Student

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return phone_number.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Student) {
        return phone_number.equals(((Student)obj).phone_number);
    }
    return false;
}
```